# Dynamically added control's on user control not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

We have a table on **aspx** page as -

```
<asp:Table ID="tblContainer" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableCell> Alplabates </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:Table>
```

and we are adding control in this table as -

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowcount = tblContainer.Rows.Count;
        // rowcount is one always
        GenerateDynamicControls();
    }



    private void GenerateDynamicControls()
    {
        int rowcount = tblContainer.Rows.Count;

        tblContainer.Visible = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            TableCell td = new TableCell();

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.ID = i + "abc";

            td.Controls.Add(textBox);
            tr.Cells.Add(td);

            tblContainer.Rows.Add(tr);

        }
    }
```

Table row count appears as one always. We tried by setting `EnableViewState=true` but no luck.

Can you please guide how can we get its value?
Thank you!

Comment: You have to recreate those controls on every page load, and that includes a PostBack.

Comment: Agree with you! But our logic of creating controls is in Page_Load Method itself. which means these are recreated on on every page load but still not getting their values.

Comment: Well, as long as they are not wrapped within a `IsPostBack` check then it should work. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that it is Sharepoint.

Comment: Hello Dear. Tried on plane asp.net but the same issue. Edited question for more clarity. Can you help with this?